# Using scrapy to loop through discovered a-href url links to scrape the corresponding pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm just starting out with Scrapy and Python, and have been following the tutorial, but am stuck. I have been able to use the shell to get a list of links from a page, as per the below:

```
>>> response.css('li').xpath('a/@href').getall()
```

Gives me:

```
'/shop-online/542/fragrances', '/shop-online/81/vitamins', '/shop-online/257/beauty', '/shop-online/665/skin-care', '/shop-online/648/cosmetics', '/shop-online/517/weight-loss', '/shop-online/20/baby-care', '/shop-online/89/sexual-health', '/shop-online/198/smoking-deterrents', '/shop-online/3240/clearance', '/prescriptions', '/shop-online/258/medicines', '/shop-online/1093/cold-flu', '/shop-online/PS-1755/all-fish-oil-supplements', '/shop-online/159/oral-hygiene-and-dental-care', '/shop-online/792/household', '/shop-online/129/hair-care', '/shop-online/1255/sports-nutrition', '/bestsellers', '/categories', 'https://www.chemistwarehouse.hk', '/', '#', '/login', '/youraccount', '#', '/aboutus', '/aboutus/shipping', '/shop-online/542/fragrances', '/shop-online/81/vitamins', '/shop-online/257/beauty', '/shop-online/665/skin-care', '/shop-online/648/cosmetics', '/shop-online/517/weight-loss', '/shop-online/20/baby-care', '/shop-online/89/sexual-health', '/shop-online/198/smoking-deterrents', '/prescriptions', '/shop-online/258/medicines', '/shop-online/1093/cold-flu', '/shop-online/PS-1755/all-fish-oil-supplements', '/shop-online/159/oral-hygiene-and-dental-care', '/shop-online/792/household', '/shop-online/129/hair-care', '/shop-online/1255/sports-nutrition', '/bestsellers']
```

What I want to be able to do, at least using the shell for now (and then scripting it) is to be able to parse out any links that don't contain shop-online, and then scrape the corresponding URLs, which will be www..website/**the link I've scraped**

But I'm not sure how to do this. I am aware there are regex expressions you can use, but I'm not sure how to apply them, and even if I could, I'm not sure how to then tell scrapy to iterate through what I've found and scrape THOSE pages?

Comment: it is text so you can use standard string functions like `if text.startswith("/shop-online/"):` or `if "/shop-online/" in text:`. And later you can do `"www.website.com/" + "/scraped-link"` or you can use `response.urljoin("/scraped-link")` See: [Response.urljoin()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) and [Response.follow()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow)

Comment: Thanks @furas so you're saying I should load the initial results into a list of some sort, then iterate through that to produce the next set(s) of results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to […] parse out any links that don't contain shop-online, and then scrape the corresponding URLs

In a spider callback, that would be:

```py
for link in response.xpath('//li//a/@href[contains(., "/shop-online/")]'):
    yield response.follow(link.get())
```

In the shell, you only can handle one request at a time, because it is only meant for debugging purposes, so you would just pick one of the links and fetch it:

```py
link = response.xpath('//li//a/@href[contains(., "/shop-online/")]').get()  # Gets the first link only
fetch(response.follow(link))
```